# Unintuitive behaviour of array.map

Tags: arrays, ruby

So this behaviour seems to be logical

```
> array = (1..4).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
> array.map {|a| [array.delete(array.first), array.delete(array.last)]}
=> [[1, 4], [2, 3]]
> array
=> []
```

But then when we increase the range it doesn't work:

```
> array = (1..6).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> array.map {|a| [array.delete(array.first), array.delete(array.last)]}
=> [[1, 6], [2, 5]]
> array
=> [3, 4]
```

And it does the same weird behaviour with odd numbers:

```
> array = (1..9).to_a
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> array.map {|a| [array.delete(array.first), array.delete(array.last)]}
 => [[1, 9], [2, 8], [3, 7]]
> array
 => [4, 5, 6]
```

This was not what we expected, why does it behave this way?

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the last two? Also, iterating over something and modifying it at the same time is generally considered to be a bad idea, it tends to lead to strange and confusing behavior unless you are very careful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess since I am not sure if this is the exact case but I can't put this as a comment.

So lets go step by step:

you defined an array:

```
> array = (1..6).to_a
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now defined an iterator:

```
array.map {|a| [array.delete(array.first), array.delete(array.last)]}
```

so for first iteration it will take `array[0]` as the value for for variable `a` and do the operation and hence deleting `first` and `last` element of the array.

After first iteration `array` becomes `[2,3,4,5]`.

For second iteration it will take `array[1]` as the value for for variable `a` and do the same as in first iteration and delete first and last element. Now `array` is `[3,4]`.

Now for 3rd iteration, well it would not have tried for 3rd iteration if your original array was only size of 2 i.e like `[2,3]` but since you modified your original array during iteration so it will attempt 3rd iteration since original array had length `6`.

For 3rd iteration it needs array's third element i.e `array[2]` but your current array does not have that index so it returns the remaining array without any other operation.

It is really confusing to modify array while being iterated.